# C++ : For Loop and Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I have been working on Codility on the task MaxCounters. And I have got stuck. No matter what I try, the following code won't loop

```
// you can also use includes, for example:
// #include <algorithm>

vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &A) 
{
    vector<int> counter (N,0);

    for (int i = 0;i < A.size();i++)
    {
        int value = A.at(i);

        if (value = A.size() + 1)
        {

        }
        else
            counter[value - 1] += 1;
    }

    return (counter);
}
```

I have used this website to find a solution to my problem but to no avail. I keep getting this error message.

> > In file included from user.cpp:20: func.cpp: In function 'std::vector > solution(int, std::vector >&)': func.cpp:7: warning: comparison between
> >     signed and unsigned integer expressions func.cpp:11: warning: suggest
> >     parentheses around assignment used as truth value

Any ideas why it just keeps throwing this error?

EDIT: After looking from the other tests, it is clear that I would get this error no matter what exercise I did. So as a result, I conclude I haven't understood looping vectors. What is the correct way to loop through a vector?

Comment: The curse of `==`... Check your if clause..

Comment: Hadn't even noticed that. The error still continues but that's prevented a future issue

Comment: When you say it wont loop, what do you mean?

Comment: One way: `for( auto value: A ) {....}` (That's C++11).  Another way: `for( vector<int>::iterator i = A.begin(); i != A.end(); ++i ) { ...`

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler is suggesting, this:

```
if (value = A.size() + 1)
```

is assigning value the value of A.size() + 1, not evaluating their equality

```
if (value == A.size() + 1)
```

Might be what you want instead.

Additionally, `size()` returns an unsigned int, not an `int`, thus the compiler complaints with regards to that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two different warnings.  The first one relates to this problem:

```
if( value = A.size() + 1)
```

...which is just a typo, and should be written as:

```
if( value == A.size() + 1 )
```

Once you've resolved that you can move on to the next warning:

An `int` is signed.  `A.size()` returns an unsigned value.  You could change `for( int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i)` to something like `for( size_t i = 0....`.

Since all of the ints you are storing are probably positive, use an appropriate container type (unsigned, for example).  Here's how it would look:

```
vector<unsigned> solution(int N, vector<unsigned> &A) 
{
    vector<unsigned> counter (N,0);

    for (size_t i = 0;i < A.size();i++)
    {
        unsigned value = A.at(i);

        if ( value == A.size() + 1 )
        {

        }
        else
            counter[value - 1] += 1;
    }

    return (counter);
}
```

The reason that comparing or assigning an unsigned to a signed is worthy of generating a warning is because the ranges of signed versus unsigned containers are different.

Comment: I think this is an issue that will curse me until I learn more about this. I gave up on the exercise because the way I programmed wouldn't work until I understand vectors in terms of looping. Would you know of a good tutorial?

The main problem is getting an int of the A.size()

Comment: It seems to me the main problem isn't casting `A.size()` as an int.  If the values you are storing in vector A are always positive, and may be compared to A.size, then you should be storing unsigned objects, not signed objects in your vector.

Comment: I don't know about online tutorials... For books, it's hard to beat "The C++ Primer" (most recent edition, and *not* "The C++ Primer Plus")

Comment: Oh btw, the return value must always be an int. It is fixed as that.

Comment: I'll be honestly, I'm lost to all this about static_cast, signed and unsigned. Would it be possible for an explanation. What do they do? How do they differ?

Comment: An int has a range from some negative value to some positive value.  An unsigned has a range from zero through some positive value about double the max for an int.  This range mismatch makes it not implicitly safe to do compiler-generated conversions between the types.  Since you're doing something that might be risky, the compiler complains with a warning, but lets you do it anyway.  Since you are (hopefully) sure that in this case it's safe, you can `static_cast<int>(i)` where necessary, and leave the function otherwise as you've got it (after fixing the if == issue).

Comment: static_cast tells both the compiler and someone reading your code in the future that you're doing something that you believe to be ok even though in principle it carries risks.  Later if someone has to debug, they might see that as one area to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You program should be updated in the following way

1. This should avoid the comparing the comparison between signed and unsigned integer.

   for (int i = 0;i < A.size();i++)

TO

```
   for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0;i < A.size();i++)
```

1. As your loop is taking care of *size()*, you should use [] operator instead of *at* as
   internally it do have check for out-of-bound access. This can be avoided.

   int value = A.at(i);

TO

```
 int value = A[i];
```

1. This is actually a main problem and in your code as you have used = instead of ==.

   if (value = A.size() + 1)

TO

```
   if (value == A.size() + 1)
```

Comment: `Compiler output:
In file included from user.cpp:20:
func.cpp: In function 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > solution(int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)':
func.cpp:9: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions`

Comment: Well, I'm trying to this exercise. `https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/max_counters`. And to solve it, you need to loop through the vector. And I wasn't doing it wrong. I followed your instructions as you detailed

Comment: Sorry I mistook. I have reset my code back to what it was at the start of the topic

https://codility.com/c/run/demoGG9VAY-7G8

Have a tinker around. Perhaps you can see something I missed. Btw, the = was a typo. I did mean ==. It's been a long day